# Why are there two Wifi indicators in the panel?

Tags: indicator, menu-bar

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 en noticed that I have two indicators for WIFI in my upper panel.

In my 'panel' (where the clock is) I can see the time, a little envelope, a battery, an icon to adjust the sound etc.

And a symbol that shows me that I'm connected to the internet. BUT, I have 2 of these icons side by side. A normal one and one with a lock on it.

[image]

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [Two Wifi Icons in panel](http://askubuntu.com/q/364717/88802)