# Two Wifi Icons in Panel

Tags: wireless, indicator

I have the exact problem in 13.10 as this user
[Why are there two Wifi indicators in the panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363755/two-wifi-indicators-in-panel).

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Here are some screenshots from another user: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2183020&p=12825563

[image]

ifconfig and iwconfig outputs

```
$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:XXXXXX  Mask:XXXXXXX
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:209889 (209.8 KB)  TX bytes:209889 (209.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XXXXXXXXX  
          inet addr:XXXXXX  Bcast:XXXXXXXX  Mask:XXXXXXX
          inet6 addr: XXXXXXX Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5925 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3361 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2951818 (2.9 MB)  TX bytes:630579 (630.5 KB)

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"XXXXX"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: XXXXXXXX
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:153  Invalid misc:472   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: A screen shot would actually be nice here, but yes, probably a bug. Is it a clean install?

Comment: Please, try again uploading a screenshot - or just add a dropbox/ubuntu-one link to a .png file and someone will edit it into your question for you.

Comment: so far it looks like your network manager is showing a wired network (right icon with lock) and a wireless network (left icon)

Comment: They are both wireless networks. You can see the pull down menus in the 3rd post of the thread on the Ubuntu forums.

Comment: On the 3rd post it shows that one reads "draadloze network = wireless" and the other "Wired = bekabeld"? Those 2 application indicators are in different languages...

Comment: Cntrl+ Alt+ T and type `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` in your terminal. Update your question with those results.

Comment: I added the output for ifconfig and iwconfig. I also took screenshots to show that they are both wireless connections.

Comment: Looks like you have two network management applications installed. Perhaps you installed the popular WICD next to Network Manager for example? Please elaborate a bit more about what you changed to your system compared to a clean installation.

Comment: This happened after I uninstalled the gnome Bluetooth manager and installed the blueman Bluetooth manager. Later I reverted back but still had two wifi icons. Could installing the blueman package possibly have installed another wifi connection manager? WICD is not installed.

Comment: @Jonathan Rogiest I just read your profile. Always happy to get help from a fellow permie :)

Comment: @emptysenti thx fellow permie! Agree with @gertvdijk maybe reverting did not work properly. try `sudo apt-get remove --purge application` and where the word application use the name of the actual application. Example in my case I use network manager aka nm-applet so my line would be `sudo apt-get remove --purge nm-applet`

Comment: Strange, I ran your command and it returned "Unable to locate package nm-applet". However, nm-applet is one of the hidden start up apps.

Comment: You need to select the application you don't need any more. nm-applet was my example but in your scenario it might be another. Find the app you want to remove using this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126268/how-to-find-out-the-terminal-command-of-an-application)

Comment: so in case you want to remove blueman bluetooth manager and the command line for that app is for example `blueman` then you should do the following `sudo apt-get remove --purge blueman` This [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoftwareManagement) will also help since there are different ways of removing packages/software/applications.

Comment: did you happen to install unity8 to try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The one with the shorter menu (on the right in the screenshots) is "indicator-network", removing it and its associated system settings application (you are prompted for this when you remove indicator-network) will remove it from the bar. You can remove it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-network
```

I had the same problem after I stopped network manager autorunning and then enabled it again.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Removing it will also remove several needed package `ubuntu-system-settings ...`. Do you know how to disable/hide it?

Comment: I just removed the system settings application as well, so sorry I can't help you there

Answer (score 1):

### For Lubuntu users only:

From the main menu select *Preferences* > *Default applications for LXSession*. In the window that then appears, click on the *Autostart* tab, then click the remove button next to *@nm-applet* in the section *Manual autostarted applications*.

[image: "Default applications for LXSession" window]

Log off then on again, and there should now be just one icon.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, the reason was a second desktopmanager (mate), i had installed. After i cleaned the /etc/xdg from the files where mate is inside i have only one icon.
maybe there was something doubble.

greatings

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when upgrading to Ubuntu 16.10. I solved it by starting "Startup Applications" and unselecting "indicator-network"

[image: taking indicator-network startup]