# Double icons in task bar, other icons don't stay

Tags: wireless, printing, icons, taskbar

I am using Lubuntu (Operating System : Ubuntu 13.10). I have double icons for network connections/WiFi on the taskbar by clock. How do I get it to one(merge them), it seems like duplicates? FYI this did not work-[Two Wifi Icons in Panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364717/two-wifi-icons-in-panel)

Additionally, the `xfce4-power-manager 1.2.0` icon is set to stay on for Power Manager and each time I boot it does not stay on. Its in this screen shot but each time I reboot it goes away

Neither does the HP printer device manager icon for HPLIP-3.14.1 doesn't stay on either.

Last the power button/logoff button is missing as it was originally there in the right taskbar/panel

[image]

NOTE: HPLIP had a software update to 3.14.3 and since then my HP and xfce Power manager icon now comes on.

Still don't know about the double Icons though...

This post and help by Stormvirux got me back to the original config of taskbar with the power button back-but still have the double wifi icons-
[restore shutdown button on taskbar? How do you restore desktop taskbar in Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429587/restore-shutdown-button-on-taskbar-how-do-you-restore-desktop-taskbar-in-lubunt)

Comment: Could you add a screenshot then? Upload it to a place like imgur and edit the link into your question.

Comment: how do you do a screenshot with Lubuntu? I tried using print screen but that didnt work. also noticed that ctrl C and Ctrl v and ctrl x don't work???

Comment: do I still need to be on hold???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two Wifi Icons in Panel](http://askubuntu.com/questions/364717/two-wifi-icons-in-panel).  See the later added answer http://askubuntu.com/a/491826/425479